# People left mean comments on my question, how do I resolve this?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, voting

I [wrote the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879835/net-framework-stack-overflow-bug), and it received a lot of bad spirited comments. How do I fix this situation? Do I need to delete the question and start over? Should it be edited? What mistake did I make in asking the question?

Comment: Since when does asking the "OP" or the guy/gal who posted the question to provide the code for review from people WILLING to answer your question.  Seems like a no brainer to me...

Comment: You are not responding to other users' requests for information. You are ignoring them. Unfortunately I'm out of votes today...

Comment: You've received 9 upvotes, and 11 downvtoes as of now.  That means you had a total positive reputation gain of 45-22=23.  I would recommend that you don't delete the question, but instead consider responding to the comments.  Showing more code, and showing the stack trace will likely lead you very quickly to the problem.

Comment: What a turn of events. It turns out that it was a bug in the .Net framework after all. Of course this couldn't be seen from the original question, so after a bit of heartache, and the OP responding with more detail, there are now some good answers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some of the comments are borderline, but overall the problem is that you're being told something by the community ("Hey, post the code we need to see."), but you haven't responded to them.  You haven't provided that code, and to top it off, you're jumping to the conclusion that it must be a problem in .NET.

If you'd like better comments on your posts, try the following approach:

1. Post all relevant code.
2. Assume that [Select isn't broken](http://www.travisswicegood.com/2009/01/04/select-isn-t-broken/).
3. Be engaged in your post, and when people come up with questions, update your post to answer those questions.

Comment: The point about being engaged is important, but it is also a natural mistake for new users to make: most help sites on the internet are *slow* by comparison.

Comment: +1 agreed.  The reason I say he isn't engaged is because he took the time to write out a meta post complaining about their behavior, but didn't take the time to address their behavior.

Comment: A fine "Moderator" worthy response...

Comment: i am sorry i realize i should not have complained here. i was frustrated with problem and comments made me worse. i had my friend write explanation better to write what i am trying to do and write comments here to provide explanation. thank you for the help

Answer (score 4):

The comments seem to suggest that you haven't included enough information for someone else to reproduce the problem.  Further, others suggest that you check the stack trace to find out where the stack is overflowing.

Your lack of responses to the comments suggests that you haven't fixed the first problem (ie, give enough code to show the problem) and that you haven't followed the second recommendation.

If you aren't able to provide enough code, or follow simple debugging steps, people can't help you out much.

Comment: But where is he responding to the comments?

Comment: @Pekka - Sorry, I mis-wrote that.  Fixed.

Comment: i will consider this but i may not make recovery for bad question reps can i delete question to post better??

Comment: @Prashant - If you flag the question for moderator attention, request that it be deleted, and that your reputation be recalculated, then your reputation will go back to where it was prior to asking the question.  I suggest that you spend some time answering other people's questions before asking more of your own.  By answering other people's questions you'll get a better idea of how questions should be asked, and you'll get a better sense of the community here.

Comment: @Prashant P Your best bet is to edit the question, or have someone else edit the question. I went ahead and edited it so maybe it'll stop losing votes.

Comment: @Prashant: Currently you've gained 21 rep (+45, -24) for a very poor question. I would edit it so that it's *not* a bad question, and be done with it.

Answer (score 3):

The question, and the assumption that there must be a bug in .NET, may indeed have been dumb (I can't judge it) but this looks pretty excessive both on the vote count, and in the comments, especially seeing as the OP hasn't yet responded to anything. I think the users there are being dicks, and this is not the way SO is supposed to work.

Comment: +1, I could understand a -2 or -3 just because of the possible presumptuousness but it was at -9 for a while there which is just folks piling on

Comment: The history of *"I found a bug in [the compiler|very common library]"* posts on Stack Overflow has seem a fair amount of pile on like that. Seems odd to me since *everyone* has a moment like that early on.

Comment: I agree with this completely, many comments were uncalled for and have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking questions that are:

- Not clear
- Not the best English

To top it off you are not responding to comments where other users are clearly asking for more information so that they can help you.

Sorry, but you deserve to be down-voted when not responding to comments when your questions leave a lot to be desired.

Monitor your questions and comments and be more responsive.

Comment: You deserve nine downvotes and asshole comments if you don't respond to comments *within one hour*? I don't agree. If people obviously deliberately ignore comments (i.e. respond to some and ignore others), I'm the first to vote down. But for all we know, he just returned to his question and found it in the state it is in now.

Comment: @Pekka I certainly don't agree with asshole comments and didn't say I did, but I think if you're learning the ropes asking a poor question and then pissing off for an hour is pretty bad form too. I scanned his question history, so it wasn't an off-the-cuff remark. It's not as if you have to wait more than 1 minute for feedback on SO...

Comment: @chibacity okay, I didn't see the question history. Still, the nature of SO as almost a "live chat" is hard to grasp in the beginning, there should be *some* leeway

Comment: @Pekka Tough love is sometimes the *right* love.

Comment: @chibacity I wholeheartedly agree with that. But this is just people being dicks... Anyway, let's hope the OP learned his lessons. :)

Comment: @Pekka Agreed - Sometimes ripping someone's arm off and beating them around the head with the soggy end is the *right* thing to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can see both sides of this - on one hand you should have posted the code and jumping to the conclusion that "it's a bug in .NET" is a bit ridiculous (yes, there are bugs in .NET but what do you think is more likely a bug in this scenario?) It's also not that clear on the language front and on the face of it could've been phrased a lot better.

That said, a vote count of -6 and below is in my mind a bit excessive, I've seen far worse questions get of much lighter and I've upvoted the question to try and balance things out a bit (not because I think it's a good question but because I don't think it deserves a score quite that low!)

So yes, in my mind people are being a tad unreasonable there. But calling people "dicks" and not updating your question to reflect the changes requested won't do you any favours.

If you want to try and redeem the situation somewhat, I'd edit the original question, post the code people want to see, phrase things much better and apologise for the poor quality of the original post. People are generally much more likely to give you a second opinion and help out if you apologise and provide the material that's needed to answer the question properly in a clear format.